# Why is this not a stopping time?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

I am going through Shreve's Stochastic Calculus book and he has a random time $\rho$ defined as follows:
$$\rho(HH) = 0, \quad \rho (HT) = 0, \quad \rho(TH) = 1, \quad \rho(TT) = 2$$

which he claims is not a stopping time. I was under the impression that this is, as $\rho(HX) = 0$, regardless of time outcome of $X$. Would anyone be able to clear up where I have misunderstood? Thanks.

Comment: -1 for an unclear question out of any context.

Comment: Sorry if I missed an edit, but what is unclear or lacking context here?  The context is the question asker is working through a stochastic calculus book and found a claim they don't understand, the question is "why is this random variable not a stopping time?"  They explained why they thought it would be to help clarify as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a stopping time because $\{\omega : \rho(\omega) \le 1 \} = \{HH,HT,TH\}$ is not in $\mathcal F_1 = \{\emptyset,\Omega,\{HH,HT\},\{TH,TT\}\}.$

Comment: Thank you, could you explain where $\rho(\omega) \leq 1$ came from?

Comment: To be a stopping time, we need $\{\rho \le t \} \in \mathcal F_t$ for all $t$.  I looked at the event $\{\rho \le 1 \}$ specifically because whether or not $\rho$ is $1$ or $2$ depends on the second toss, so it isn't known at time $1$.

Comment: I think I get it. Just to be sure, so for the $n$-th coin toss to have a stopping time we need $\{ \rho \leq n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n$?

Comment: Yes, I think that's right, but it might be a little more clear to say "for $\rho$ to be a stopping time we need $\{\rho \le n \} \in \mathcal F_n$ for all $n$," just to make it clear that we can't have something that's a stopping time for some $n$ but not others.

Comment: Great thanks for all the help!